# Given two functions with recurrence relations and starting values, prove that $f(2020)<5$

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, contest-math

There are two functions $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R^+$ and $g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R^+$. For all $n\in \mathbb N$: $$f(1)=1$$ $$g(1)=2$$ $$f(n+1)=\frac{1+f(n)+f(n)g(n)}{g(n)}$$$$g(n+1)=\frac{1+g(n)+f(n)g(n)}{f(n)}$$
Prove that $f(2020)<5$.

Notes:

- It appears that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=5$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=\infty$, though I haven't been able to prove either of these statements.
- First few results: $f(1)=1; f(2)=2; f(3)=2.6; f(4)=3.05$ and $g(1)=2; g(2)=5; g(3)=8; g(4)=11.\overline{461538}$.

Comment: Hello haal, could you add the source of the problem? It looks like a contest question - no offense intended.

Comment: I can show that $g$ goes to infinity, but not that $f$ goes to $5$. With this hypotesis of $g$ can you do something?

Comment: It is an amended version of a task from Day 2 of the 2020 Mathematical Olympiad in Latvia. I am yet to find the tasks on the internet though. As for $g$ going to infinity, while it should be true, I don't know yet how it would be useful in proving the limit for $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f(n+1) + 1= \frac{(f(n)+1)(g(n)+1)}{g(n)}$ and for $g(n+1)$ a similar equation. With this we get 
$$\frac{1}{f(n+1)+1}-\frac{1}{g(n+1)+1} = \frac{1}{f(n)+1}-\frac{1}{g(n)+1} = \frac{1}{f(1)+1}-\frac{1}{g(1)+1} =\frac{1}{6}$$
and therefore $ \frac{1}{f(n)+1} = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{g(n)+1}>\frac{1}{6}\Rightarrow f(n)<5$.

The solution is short but it doesn't explain much. :/